Chrome blocks download csv with selenium
I have a script to download a csv file. It runs perfectly until the last step. Chrome blocks the download of the CSV_file.
Tried all kind of options and prefs. I am running out of options.
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": "D:/Lokale schijf/COMPANYNAME/datafiles/SOFTWEAR_STOCKDATA",  # Verander dit naar je gewenste downloadmap
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True,
   
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
options.add_argument("--disable-features=DownloadBubble,DownloadBubbleV2");



# Start de webdriver (gebruik Chrome of een andere driver die bij jouw browser past)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

don't want to switch to other browser.

Impossible to be sure without knowing what your URL is

Found the sollution. Problem was in the definition of the download path. Selenium requires a path with double "\" in stead of "/" separators.
adjusted prefs:
prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": "D:\\Lokale schijf\\COMPANYNAME\\datafiles\\SOFTWEAR_STOCKDATA",  
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True,

